# AVD Manager missing "Automotive" Category

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm running Android Studio 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

I need to create an `Automotive` type virtual device but when I try to create a new virtual device, the `Select Hardware` dialog is missing the `Automotive` category altogether.

[image]
Trying to follow the instructions at 
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#auotmotive-avd

and

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/automotive-getting-started/#2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the `New Hardware Profile` to find this option.

[image]

And then select Hardware as Automotive.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @GensaGames. I already had tried that but when I go next screen, somehow it's unable to find any system images (I guess for Android Automotive) and can't continue further

Comment: @kaushal It's another question. I just answered what you asked above.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue.
Had to install latest Android studio 4.0 canary and required category appeared